# How to clip selected polygon with ogr2ogr

Tags: clip, ogr2ogr

I have a problems with clipping two vector layers. 1 with 7 polygons (layer-A) and the other has many polygons (Layer-B).
When i start clipping with Layer-B as input and Layer-A as overlay a get a clipping output of all polygons in Layer-A
How can i get only output of one of the polygons in layer-A ??
The polygons have a ID's 1 ..... 7
Can i select on one of these ??

I have tried
ogr2ogr.exe -progress -f "ESRI Shapefile"  -clipsrcwhere "ID = 4"  -clipsrc "Layer-B.shp" "clipt.shp"  "Layer-A.shp"  -overwrite

Comment: Maybe I understood wrong, but if you want to filter the source data "Layer-A.shp", use `-where`, not `clipsrcwhere`.

Comment: Thank you. That 's does the job. The only thing i mis now are the atributes of the clipt layer. I get the atributes of the overlay layer. Any idee ??